# while loop which executes five times and each time displaying a random digit

Tags: java

I'm trying to create program segment that uses a single while loop which executes its loop body five times, each time displaying a random digit from this set of values. { 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6 } 
The while loop executes only once `enter code here`

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        int num = 0;
        int count = 0;
        while (count < 5)
            count ++;
        num = (int)(Math.random()* 6);

    System.out.println(num);
```

I also tried to do that with arrays.

```
 public static void main(String[] args){
            int[] num = { 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6 };
            int count = 0;
            while (count < 5)
                count++;
            num [count] = (int)(Math.random()* 6);                   
            System.out.println(num);
```

Any tips will be helpful.

Comment: Have you heart of the for loop? It easier to use than a while loop when you know how many times you want to loop in advance - but it is certainly possible with a while loop as well.

Comment: `(int)(Math.random() * 6)` returns a random number between 0 and 5, inclusive.

Comment: I needed a while loop for this. I know it is easier with for loop.

Answer (score 1):

The `while` loop has no braces, so the body is only the next statement. Which increments `count`. Add braces.

```
while (count < 5) {
    count ++;
    num = (int) (Math.random() * 6);
    System.out.println(num);
}
```

Or, in Java 8+, with an `IntStream` like

```
IntStream.generate(() -> (int) (Math.random() * 6))
        .limit(5).forEachOrdered(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Worth noting that the auto-indentation pointed this out. Always pay attention to it.

Comment: In Java 8 you can use `new Random().ints(5, 1, 7)`.

Comment: Hah. I swear i tried that before and it didn't work.

Comment: Ok, but now i'm also getting a random 0 popping up. How can i get rid of that?

Comment: @Ilias `Math.random() * 6` is giving you numbers in the (inclusive) range `0 - 5`. If you want `1 - 6`, just add 1. `1 + (int) (Math.random() * 6);`

Comment: That  works.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the last two lines inside the while loop

eg:

```
int[] num = { 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6 };
int count = 0;
while (count < 5) {
    count++;
    num = (int)(Math.random()* 6);                   
    System.out.println(num);
}
```

Another solution would be to use a 'for' loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    num = (int)(Math.random()* 6);                   
    System.out.println(num);
}
```